# How can I get rid of crops?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I have way more grass growing than I could ever use. I want to grow other things there, so how can I get rid of the crop that's growing? I tried hoeing it and using my sickle, but it didn't seem to clear the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of grass hammer it until it turns into a field of brown wilted plants and then use the sickle to remove the remains. Hammer it one more time if you don't want the tilled field there anymore as well.

[image: Smashing Grass Field]
[image: Result: Wilted Plants]

For regular crops that have sprouted you can use sickle to remove them. For crops that are still seeds you need to use the hoe.

Comment: I've used the hoe on sweet potatoes to destroy them and it works. I think you can use either hoe or hammer.

Comment: @Rapitor On sprouted crops the hoe and hammer damage the crop, eventually turning them into brown wilted plants just like the grass in the example above. Using the sickle on sprouted crops just removes them altogether in one swipe, saving both time and stamina. The hoe seems to be the only way to remove crops from a field when they're still seeds.